select multiple customers and check validation; a valid error message shows if incorrect
if i am selecting the customer and check for valid error then its not showing me at that time this error massage, after the selecting the next three or four customer its showing error massage for the first customerenter image description here
This is my method to select the multiple customer-
cy.fixture('customers').then((data) => {
const customers = data.results.slice(0, 55); // Limit to first 55 customers
        customers.forEach((customer) => {
            cy.get('div.vue-recycle-scroller__item-wrapper > div.vue-recycle-scroller__item-view')
                .find('label.v-label > div.option-label')
                .contains(customer.name)
                .then(($custNames) => {
                    const customerName = $custNames.text().trim();
                    cy.log("CustomerName: " + customerName);

                    // Scroll to and click on the checkbox
                    cy.wrap($custNames)
                        .closest('div.vue-recycle-scroller__item-view')
                        .find('div.v-input--selection-controls__input > input[type="checkbox"]')
                        .scrollIntoView()
                        .click({ force: true });

                    // Wait for email field to be visible and interact with it
                    cy.wrap($custNames).closest('div.vue-recycle-scroller__item-view').then($view => {
                        const $emailField = $view.find('input[type="email"]');

                        if ($emailField.length) {
                            cy.wrap($emailField).should('be.visible').invoke('val').then((val) => {
                                const emailToUse = customer.email || `${customerName.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '')}@gmail.com`;
                                const baseEmail = 'test@yopmail.com'; // Base email for random generation

                                // Generate a random email if customer.email is not defined
                                const emailToType = emailToUse || cy.randomEmailGenerator(baseEmail);

                                // Clear and type the email with a double-click after typing
                                cy.wrap($emailField).clear().type(emailToType.toString(), { force: true }).trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 9, which: 9 });
                                
                                cy.wrap($emailField).should('have.value', emailToType); // Assertion for email value

                                // Wait for any potential error message to appear
                                cy.wait(2000);

                                const $errorMsg = $view.find('div.v-messages__wrapper > div.v-messages__message');

                                if ($errorMsg.length) {
                                    cy.wrap($errorMsg).invoke('text').then((text) => {
                                        if (text.includes('Email belongs to an existing Numerik user') ||
                                            text.includes('Email has been used on another customer in this list') ||
                                            text.includes('Required')) {
                                            // Log the problematic email
                                            cy.log(`Error: ${text}. Email causing the error: ${emailToType}`);

                                            // Clear the field and type a new random email
                                            cy.wrap($emailField).clear();
                                            const randomEmail = cy.randomEmailGenerator(baseEmail);
                                            cy.wrap($emailField).type(randomEmail, { force: true })
                                                .should('have.value', randomEmail);
                                            cy.log(`Random Email Used: ${randomEmail}`);
                                        } else if (text.includes('Email is invalid')) {
                                            // Log the problematic email
                                            cy.log(`Error: ${text}. Email causing the error: ${emailToType}`);

                                            // Clear the field and type a new simple email
                                            cy.wrap($emailField).clear();
                                            const simpleEmail = `${customerName.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase()}@yopmail.com`;
                                            cy.wrap($emailField).type(simpleEmail, { force: true })
                                                .should('have.value', simpleEmail);
                                            cy.log(`Simple Email Used: ${simpleEmail}`);
                                        } else {
                                            // Ensure error message does not exist
                                            cy.wrap($errorMsg).should('not.exist');
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    cy.log('No error message visible. Moving to the next customer.');
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            cy.log('Input with type="email" not found for ' + customerName + '. Skipping to next customer.');
                        }
                    });
                });
        });

        cy.log("Processed first 55 Customers");
    });

i am trying to select the multiple customer form the list, and if the selected customer showing me email field then checking the 3 condition,
1- if email is form the existing user then retype the new using randomgenerate method and go ahed to selct the next customer
2- if Email has been used on another customer in this list, then clear the eamil field and rewrite new email, and then select the next customer
3- if the email field is showing me requried then simple write the new eamil and go ahed for the select the next customer.
